# Eclipse 4.6 and GWT Designer

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

is there any version of GWt Designer, that i can use in Eclipse 4.6 ?
I have 4.6 in the gwt plugin, but i cant use the designer to edit the webpages by wysiwyg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWt Designer not has support by google, so the newest gwt version are not compatible with Designer. So, the answer is no.